# comparing original array with a deep clone, not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, clone

I am trying to test if my deep clone of an array is identic to the original object (jQuery available).

Here is how I clone it

```
self.slides = jQuery.extend(true, {}, parent.modules[self.moduleId].composed);
```

However, I end up with two slightly different objects, so even if the actual content that I am concerned with is identic, these two objects aren't. If I dump them in chrome console, this is  how they look:

Original object:

```
[Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Clone:

```
Object {0: Object}
0: Object
__proto__: Object
```

So the clone appears to actually be an object (or an object of type object) while the original seem to be an array (or object of type array).

Is there another way of cloning or how can I perform this identic-test?

Comment: _Array_ is a type of _Object_, if the clone algorithm doesn't know to create a new _Array_, it will "fall back" to creating a generic _Object_. Further, you're `extend`ing, which is a little different to making a _clone_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to clone any object would be

```
var array1 = [1, [2], 3];
var array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));
```

You can check them like this

```
console.log(array1, array2);
// [ 1, [ 2 ], 3 ] [ 1, [ 2 ], 3 ]

array1[1][0] += 3;

console.log(array1, array2);
// [ 1, [ 5 ], 3 ] [ 1, [ 2 ], 3 ]
```

Comment: I went with your suggestion and now have my app running as intended, thanks. I did however try multiple non-JSONstringify methods to compare the two resulting arrays, none of which worked for me (even really high voted answers), the only way I could have a true on the equality test was to convert both arrays to string (JSONstringify)... odd.

Answer (score 0):

this occurs because you are passing an object "{}" extender to try to clone this way, I believe it is much better

```
var clone = myArray.slice(0);
```

Comment: But then all the objects I might have inside my original array will not be cloned but merely referenced by the clone, right? This is unacceptable since I will need to be able to change the content of the original array without having it affect the clone (my whole purpose in cloning).

Comment: do not. what you are doing is to extend this object "{}" with the values ​​of this "parent.modules [self.moduleId]. composed".they are different objects.